# Keeping reference when wrapping python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, inheritance

I'd like to write a dict subclass in python3, that wraps some of the dict methods and returns instances of the same class instead of dict on `__getitem__`, if requested value happens to be a dict. Otherwise, I'd like to have behavior that is exactly identical to that of the dict. This is what I've came up with:

```
class WrappedDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, stuff, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WrappedDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.stuff = stuff

    def update_stuff(self):
        pass  # Do things with stuff

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update_stuff(*args, **kwargs)
        super(WrappedDict, self).update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        obj = super(WrappedDict, self).__getitem__(item)
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            return WrappedDict(self.stuff + str(item), obj)
        else:
            return obj
```

This however, is not identical to dict in that it doesn't return a reference to a dict value, but a new object created from that dict. To illustrate what I mean:

```
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 4}}
d1.update(a=10)
d2 = d1['c']
d2.update(d=40)
print(d1)
```

would give:

```
{'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 40}}
```

but doing the same with `WrappedDict`:

```
wd1 = WrappedDict("stuff", {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 4}})
wd1.update(a=10)
wd2 = wd1['c']
wd2.update(d=40)
print(wd1)
```

gives:

```
{'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 4}}
```

Note 4 in the inner dict instead of expected 40. Is there a way to replicate former behavior without too much of black magic?

Comment: FWIW, sub-classing the built-in types can be a little painful. You may find it easier to work with the Abstract Base Classes, eg [Mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping)

Comment: Unfortunately, isinstance(wrapped_instance, dict) must be True, so that won't work for me. But thank you for your input anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your newly created `WrappedDict` back to your object with `__setitem__`:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    obj = super(WrappedDict, self).__getitem__(item)
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        wrapped = WrappedDict(self.stuff + str(item), obj)
        super(WrappedDict, self).__setitem__(item, wrapped)
        return wrapped
    else:
        return obj
```

Full code:

```
class WrappedDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, stuff, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WrappedDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.stuff = stuff

    def update_stuff(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass  # Do things with stuff

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update_stuff(*args, **kwargs)
        super(WrappedDict, self).update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        obj = super(WrappedDict, self).__getitem__(item)
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            wrapped = WrappedDict(self.stuff + str(item), obj)
            super(WrappedDict, self).__setitem__(item, wrapped)
            return wrapped
        else:
            return obj

d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 4}}
d1.update(a=10)
d2 = d1['c']
d2.update(d=40)
print(d1)

wd1 = WrappedDict("stuff", {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 4}})
wd1.update(a=10)
wd2 = wd1['c']
wd2.update(d=40)
print(wd1)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 40}}
{'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 40}}
```

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Accepted. Thanks for the hint. :)